# OrientDB: Making Lucene work on fields that have hooks implemented on via ODocumentHookAbstract

Tags: encryption, lucene, orientdb

I'm trying to get my head around how to make Lucene work with fields that have server-side hooks altering their values - I'm using OrientDB 2.0.8.
Here's my scenario:

1. I define a small schema that includes
   -- a 'Student' VertexType
   -- a 'name' String property on the 'Student' vertex type
   -- a Lucene index on this 'name' property
2. I implement ODocumentHookAbstract as follows:
   -- in constructor I include: setIncludeClasses("Student")
   -- onRecordBeforeCreate -- I encrypt the 'name' property if it's not NULL
   -- onRecordBeforeUpdate -- I encrypt the 'name' property if it's not NULL (as in the case of the previous method); I return RESULT.RECORD_CHANGED
   -- onRecordBeforeRead -- I decrypt the 'name' property and return RESULT.RECORD_CHANGED
3. I seed the DB with some 'Students'
4. I try to run a query of the form: SELECT * FROM Student WHERE name LUCENE 'prefix*'

Assuming that I have student named 'John', my expectation was for the query to return 'John' if the provided 'prefix' was 'Jo' - hence going through the encryption-decryption phase transparently. However, this does not happen - i.e., the query does not return John. On the other hand, if I query for the encrypted value of John, I am able to retrieve it.

Could you please give me an idea of what am I doing wrong in this scenario? Basically, what I want is to hide the encryption step, but still to be able to query a full-text index as if encryption was not there.

Thank you!
Tudor